# How can I stop a Timeline running an observable listener from leaking memory?

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have a simple JavaFX app that has a scrolling animation of an image but after running the program a few times it begins to take longer and longer to launch. I figured there was a memory leak or something clogging up my JVM. `SimpleDoubleProperty`Oracle docs gave me this tidbit which I think is my problem.

> The ObservableValue stores a strong reference to the listener which will prevent the listener from being garbage collected and may result in a memory leak. It is recommended to either unregister a listener by calling removeListener after use or to use an instance of WeakChangeListener avoid this situation.

How can I implement this fix into my current code?

I'm a little rusty with lambda expressions and am kind of lost on where I would need to make this adjustment.

```
public class LoginController {
    public Region content;
    
    public void initialize() {
        DoubleProperty xPosition = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        xPosition.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setBackgroundPositions(content, xPosition.get()));
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(xPosition, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(200), new KeyValue(xPosition, -15000))
        );
        timeline.play();
    }
    void setBackgroundPositions(Region region, double xPosition) {
        String style = "-fx-background-position: " +
                "left " + xPosition/6 + "px bottom," +
                "left " + xPosition/5 + "px bottom," +
                "left " + xPosition/4 + "px bottom," +
                "left " + xPosition/3 + "px bottom," +
                "left " + xPosition/2 + "px bottom," +
                "left " + xPosition + "px bottom;";
        region.setStyle(style);
    }
}
```

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
        
            VBox root = (VBox)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            System.out.println("launch");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            System.out.println("Program closed");
        });
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="content" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="456.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LoginController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <center>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="e" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="129.0" />
                  <PasswordField layoutX="226.0" layoutY="161.0" />
                  <Label id="userNameLabel" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="130.0" styleClass="userNameLabel" stylesheets="@Moving.css" text="Username : " textFill="#ff0101">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="OCR A Extended" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label id="passWordLabel" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="163.0" styleClass="passWordLabel" stylesheets="@Moving.css" text="Password : " textFill="#ff0101">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="OCR A Extended" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutY="209.0" prefHeight="101.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-spacing: 10;">
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                     </cursor>
                     <children>
                        <Button id="loginBtn" fx:id="loginBtn" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="loginBtn" stylesheets="@Moving.css" text="Log In" />
                        
                        <Button id="registerBtn" fx:id="registerBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" prefWidth="80.0" styleClass="registerBtn" stylesheets="@Moving.css" text="Register" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </center>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
         </cursor>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@application.css" />
      <URL value="@Moving.css" />
   </stylesheets>
   <cursor>
      <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
   </cursor>
</VBox>
```

Tried replacing xPosition.addlistener functions with a WeakChangeListener but it was not compatible with the current code configuration.

Comment: You seem to assume that the cause of your performance issue is a reference to a listener.  It is not.  On the other hand styling the background position using css every frame may be suspect.   So your actual problem and required solution are likely unrelated to the question.  In short, it is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Understand this and take action accordingly.

Comment: The `SimpleDoubleProperty` will be garbage collected some time after the `Timeline` finishes, because only the `Timeline` has a strong reference to it (the `Timeline` never escapes the method, and so it will only be strongly referenced while it is running). And given the only strong reference to that listener is by the property, when the property is GC'd so will the listener be GC'd. In other words, this is unlikely to be the source of your issue, at least not based on the code in the question. I suggest profiling your application to find where the slowdown is coming from.

Comment: @jewelsea actually it looks like that was the problem. I used setOnCloseRequest to manually run garbage collector each time the app closes and it works perfectly now no slow start ups. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "no slow start ups" -- I missed that your problem was during the start up of your application. In that case, it makes _even less sense_ that this listener could be your problem. Likely something else is going on. All memory is released when the process terminates. And even if you had two instances of your application running simultaneously, let alone starting a new instance after the previous one terminates, they wouldn't share memory. Also, you can't force the GC to run. If you're calling `System.gc()` then that's only a _request_; the GC may or may not honor that request.

Comment: @slaw Really? That's weird because ever since I requested "System.gc()" on close of the app it hasn't had a problem since then. It was taking longer to open each launch. At one point it was over 5 min and running but window hadn't opened yet. Now it pops open in less than 5 seconds each time. Could this be coincidence or my hardware? The only change I made was the garbage collection.